# sql данные дублируются

Tags: sql

[table_phone_type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oGIW.png)
Вот примерный код:

```
SELECT
  string_agg(CASE WHEN pc.id IS NULL
    THEN NULL
             ELSE concat(dic.lang_value1, ': ', pc.contact_value) END, ', ') AS "contacts"
FROM tal_person person
LEFT JOIN tal_dic_phone_type dic ON dic.id = pc.type_id
```

[данные почему-то дублируются](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiwRj.png)

[image: мой запрос должен был вытащить только эти данные, то есть две записи]

Comment: Transact? Postgre? (добавьте тег) Что именно дублируется(на скрине непонятно)?

Comment: База - неодушевлённая. Как и запрос. Они ничего сами не дублируют. У Вас, скорее всего, несколько записей с одинаковым type_id в таблице tal_person.

Comment: Если дублируются строки - добавьте `distinct` в `select`

Comment: да в tal_person есть type_id и их  там много оказывается. в table_phone_type есть только два типа майл и тел.  у каждого пользователя свои контакты но проблема в том что он свои же данные то есть майл и телефон дублирует